# I want to convert pandas Timedelta to string with format

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I would like to convert pandas Timedelta to string
but as you know it differ from what Timedelta got

1. if it's `00:00:00` then
   `0 days 00:00:00`
2. but if it's `00:00:02.043000` (means it has ms info)
   `0 days 00:00:02.043000`

how can I get string with millisecond even if it has 0 ms.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's good this way. but I found a solution for me.

Situation.
- I got a column `data['time']` which `dtype` is `pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta`

What I did in one line

1. change `dtype` from `Timedelta` to `datetime`

   - `pd.to_datetime(data['time'])`
2. then I give it a format

   - `pd.to_datetime(data['time']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")`
3. I only need till 0.1 millisecond. so I remove  last 2 digit (I willl use it to make .srt file)

   - `data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")**.str[:-2]`